# Eclipse keymap in Cloud 9 IDE (ide.c9.io), is it possible?

Tags: cloud9-ide

Is there a way to use Eclipse's keymap inside Cloud9 IDE (c9.io) ? I already know many shortcuts in Eclipse so I would like to use them in Cloud9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just came across a blog post regarding this: somebody already made a start, so I guess you can use this and extend it. http://demostene.ro/2014/11/eclipse-keymap-for-cloud9-ide-c9-io.html
If you add several keybindings we might even build it in, so everybody can enjoy the Eclipse keybinding.

Answer (score 3):

Cloud9 supports custom keymaps. You can find the key map editor in the preferences. See: http://screencast.com/t/yICZYx9gDtUm. Afaik there is no eclipse keymap available yet. If you create one, it would be awesome to post it somewhere for others to find it as well.